# Calculating Angular Distance

Tags: positional-astronomy

Given the horizontal coordinates of two objects in the sky, how does one go about calculating the angular separation between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use [Spherical Trigonometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry)

Given $A_1$ and $A_2$ are the respective azimuthal coordinates of the two objects, and $a_1$, $a_2$ their respective altitudes,

the angular seperation $\theta$ is given by

$$\cos \theta = \sin a_1 \sin a_2 + \cos a_1 \cos a_2 \cos (A_1-A_2)$$

Comment: The link to spherical trigonometry is a bit misleading since that's more about spherical triangles. I think great circle distance would be a better link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance